# How fault tolerant cron job is?

Tags: shell, hadoop, cron, hive, apache-pig

I am using cron job to schedule a shell script after every 2 minutes containing pig and hive scripts. I want to know how fault tolerant cron job is, suppose if network goes down or some file getting corrupted when the job is running, what cron job is gonna do ? Is it going to restart that shell script again or what will happen. I am not getting any info on this on internet. It would b really great if you guys help.
Thanks

Comment: try it.... it would fail..

Comment: is same thing gonna happen if i use oozie instead of cron job ? I am using cron job to run my pig and hive scripts for big data purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oozie uses DAG and checks data availability when multiple scripts are launched that share it. Oozie allows you work easier with dependencies for Pig and Hive jobs. As it is integrated with Yarn you will be less afraid of blowing up the cluster.

If data is corrupted cron will do nothing, it will wait for the next execution cycle. Also you might fill the que really easy with the cron which might lead to jobs being executed longer.

Comment: i am having trouble to run my pig scripts in oozie using HUE, but same thing is working fine in cronjob. Can you provide me some samples of oozie so that i can go through them.

Answer (score 0):

Cron's only job is to execute things on a time schedule. It is up to your script to be fault/failure tolerant if that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Shadowfen. I want to know if i use oozie instead of cron job is it going to behave same ?